# Android - Passing string in an EditText using Button from fragment 1 to fragment 2

Tags: android, android-fragments

ive searched over the internet for days and coudnt find any exact solution. I have a Drawer Activity, it has a content_frame for the fragments. Fragment 1 has an EditText and Button, while Fragment 2 has TextView. Inputted string in Fragment 1 will be shown in Fragment 2 when Fragment 1 Button is clicked. Fragment 2 will then populate the content_frame, removing Fragment 1.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use Bundle to transfer string at the time of `FragmentTransaction`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an interface to communicate between fragments. See more here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html